Harmonious labeling of a graphs
is harmonic labeling possible in Mathematica?
then how to find all possible harmonic labelings on a graph using Mathematica

Look this post and this post

I have tried the automorphism one but it doesn't work for hanoi graph

What's your "it doesn't work for hanoi graph":GraphAutomorphismGroup[GraphData[{"Hanoi", 3}]]

If you tried, please post your code.
